# Cannot set iVars in XMLParser

Tags: objective-c, nsxmlparser, ivars

I've made an XMLParser class in objective-c and I can't seem to set the iVars in my shared store within the parser process, I've tried numerous ways but I'm getting nowhere.

This is my code and what is being returned, Here's hoping it's a small syntax error I've overlooked.

.h

```
@interface XMLParser : NSXMLParser <NSXMLParserDelegate>
{
    XMLParser *XMLStore;
}

@property(nonatomic, weak)NSMutableString *longitudeValue;
@property(nonatomic, weak)NSMutableString *latitudeValue;

+ (XMLParser *)sharedStore;
- (void)parseXMLAtURL:(NSURL *)url;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "XMLParser.h"

@implementation XMLParser

BOOL blockLatLong = NO;
NSMutableString *currentNodeContent;

+ (XMLParser *)sharedStore
{
    static XMLParser *XMLStore = nil;
    if (!XMLStore)
        XMLStore = [[XMLParser alloc] init];

    return XMLStore;
}

- (void)parseXMLAtURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

    parser.delegate = self;

    [parser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
    [parser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
    [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];

    [parser parse];
    NSLog(@"Long:%@, Lat:%@", XMLStore.longitudeValue, XMLStore.latitudeValue);
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    currentNodeContent = [NSMutableString stringWithString:string];
}




-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"geometry"]){
        blockLatLong = YES;
    }

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"location_type"]){
        blockLatLong = NO;
    }
}




- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if (blockLatLong){

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"lng"]){
        [XMLStore setLongitudeValue:currentNodeContent];
        NSLog(@"%@", currentNodeContent);
        NSLog(@"%@", XMLStore.longitudeValue);
    }

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"lat"]){
        [XMLStore setLatitudeValue:currentNodeContent];
        NSLog(@"%@", currentNodeContent);
        NSLog(@"%@", XMLStore.latitudeValue);
    }

    }
}


@end
```

Log

```
2013-09-23 11:19:59.606 Weathalert[640:c07] 40.7143528
2013-09-23 11:19:59.606 Weathalert[640:c07] (null)
2013-09-23 11:19:59.607 Weathalert[640:c07] -74.0059731
2013-09-23 11:19:59.607 Weathalert[640:c07] (null)
2013-09-23 11:19:59.607 Weathalert[640:c07] Long:(null), Lat:(null)
```

Comment: Are you getting any crash? Bcz your question is not clear.

Comment: No crashes, but when I call this class, the NSLogs at the bottom are returning a value for currentNodeContent but not for the iVars:latitude/longitudeValue which have both been set to the value of currentNodeContent at the appropriate time. surely where I'm being given (null) I should be given the coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you've got three instances of `XMLParser` where you could be setting the instance variable:

1. Local `NSXMLParser *parser` allocated inside `parseXMLAtURL:`,
2. Function-static `static XMLParser *XMLStore` allocated inside `sharedStore`, and
3. Instance variable `XMLParser *XMLStore;` which you never allocate, so it stays `nil`.

It is the third instance on which you try calling your setters. Since it's `nil`, the calls have no effect: `[XMLStore setLongitudeValue:...]` does nothing.

To fix this, drop the second and the third variables, along with the `+(XMLParser *)sharedStore` method. Use the regular instance properties, rather than accessing the shared one.

You can harvest the results from the local `parser` variable upon completion of the `[parser parse]` call:

```
NSLog(@"Long:%@, Lat:%@", parser.longitudeValue, parser.latitudeValue);
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't do exactly as you said, but I streamlined everything and it is now working. Thanks a million.